# localhost with self-signed loads, but 127.0.0.1 does not

Tags: google-chrome, eventstoredb

I am running eventstore-oss from WSL -- it has a self-signed certificate.

Chrome in Windows 11:

`https://localhost:2113/web/index.html#/streams`  works fine (except chrome security warning for self-signed cert)

`https://127.0.0.1:2113/web/index.html#/streams`  -- This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection.

What sense does this make?  I am binding to 127.0.0.1 in `eventstore.conf` not localhost ...
Firefox gives the same behavior.  ??

---

I created the cert with these 2 commands from this doc:
https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v5/security.html#setting-up-ssl-on-linux

```bash
openssl req \
  -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/CN=eventstore.com" \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout eventstore.pem -out eventstore.csr

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey eventstore.pem \
  -in eventstore.csr -out eventstore.p12
```

I also see this behavior out-of-the-box on the windows.zip

run `.\EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --dev`

and you can hit it with `https://localhost:2113` but not `https://127.0.0.1:2113`

Even though console says its bound to `127.0.0.1`

```
[24584,15,11:39:34.858,INF] ========== ["127.0.0.1:2113"] SYSTEM INIT...
```

Comment: What's the CN and SANs in the certificate? Is 127.0.0.1 there?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I'm having trouble reading the encrypted file, but I added how I created it to my answer

Comment: These instructions are for v5, what version are you actually using? Your other questions seem to be related to the latest version. Newer versions documentation mention the certificate generation tool https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v23.6/security.html#certificate-generation-tool

Comment: You can always inspect the cert file using openssl or just opening it on Windows as a normal file (double click) and it will show the cert details. When you reach the UI (using localhost), you can also click on the lock icon in the browser address tab, and inspect the certificate there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the v5 thing.  I guess its not worth it to bother with self-signing..  Insecure mode for development (I'm using docker) and then I'll figure out certificates when I go into production.

Comment: There's an example in the docs for running a three-node cluster in Docker Compose in secure mode.